# Should I install multiple mysql servers in my dedicated server?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a dedicated server that hosts about 70 domains... some are just plain php static websites, others are wordpress websites and a few others are on ruby on rails.

In the past few days I have experienced very slow queries on mysql server...

Queries like:
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 5
takes 1.8 secs...

I enabled the slow queries log and found that all the wordpress sites dont have their databases indexed... i dont know if this is the cause of my problem.....

So the question is should i install different mysql servers for wordpress websites and ruby based websites? Or just a little tunning to the my.cnf file will do?

Comment: just to be clear - please show `EXPLAIN` for problematic query.

Comment: You can use the ` character to format your code in the comments section. :)

Comment: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 5;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |       | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)`

Comment: Weird... directly from mysql console the query is super fast, but when i execute it from a ruby app or navicat client is super slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well considering that you are not augmenting the hardware. I belive installing instance servers or even installing Virtual servers would not help you.  You should really try tuning the databases and adding valuable indicies where necessary.

Comment: If he has IO bottleneck then probably adding another hdd and moving some of databases there would help.

Comment: How can i move the databases to another hdd ?

Comment: If it is MyISAM (i bet it is) - then you can just move database datafiles to another partition and create symlinks back to the original location. but before this i think more deep research should be done. At least you have to make sure that the trouble is in IO (with help of `iostat` for example).

Answer (score 0):

Use a second server for your DB. That way your 70 sites' ruby & php scripts aren't fighting mysql for disk io and mysql can take better advantage of caching.